# Node render page after database operation with ajax call

Tags: node.js, ajax, promise

I'm trying to render a page after some database operation has completed. If I go in the console>network>preview it does display what I want, but not on the actual page. What am I doing wrong, is it just the fact that I'm using an ajax call?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Promise.all([verifylogin(req.query.field1)])
        .then(
            data => {
                res.send(`<h1>something here</h1>`);


            }
        ).catch(
            // Log the rejection reason
            (reason) => {
                console.log('Handle rejected promise (' + reason + ') here.');
                res.redirect(303, '/thank-you');
            });


});
```

this is what is calling the server code on the front end:

```
$('#login').on("click", () => {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $.get("/register", {
            field1: email,
            field2: password
        });
    });
```

Do I need to use a form instead of Ajax?

Comment: The answer from Aritra works but I'm curious why res.redirect doesn't work because I'd want to redirect the user to their section instead of staying on /home.

Comment: edited the answer, ideally you should have commented below my answer if you wanted to clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the route is correct (`/register` not `/`) You are getting the `<h1>something here</h1>` response but not writing anywhere(or not showing anywhere).

```
$('#login').on("click", () => {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.get("/register", {
        field1: email,
        field2: password
    })
    .done(data => { 
        //write somewhere
        $('#someid').html(data);
    });
});
```

But you need to look at the `catch` portion as well, it is simply redirecting to another page. But you are doing Ajax, so it will return the redirected page content.

**EDIT:**
Why redirect doesn't work?

Let's say you want to `GET` a route for example, `/route1` which returns some html. Another route is `/route2` which internally redirects to `/route1`.

So, if you `HTTP GET` `/route2` what do you think the output will be? it will be contents of `route1`. Because internally it is redirecting to `/route1`, so basically it is same as fetching the content of `/route1`.

I have made a POC for understanding:

```
app.get('/:id', (req,res)=>{
    if(req.params.id === '2'){
        res.redirect('/3');
    }else{
        res.send(req.params.id || "products");
    }
});
```

for this route,

```
fetch('http://host/1').then((d)=>d.text()).then(console.log)  //returns 1
fetch('http://host/3').then((d)=>d.text()).then(console.log)  //returns 3
```

**Workaround**:
In your catch block you can return the url, and in the `#login` handler you can add `window.location.href = <theurl>` in case of error.